# Display pdf with file selected from file input in iFrame

Tags: pdf.js

Is it possible to display a pdf file that is uploaded from a file input in an iframe with pdf.js?

Comment: OP, [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774364/wrap-function-in-before-and-after-callbacks-in-javascript) and then deleting it without even commenting on the answer is very rude.

Answer (score 1):

Use address returned by `URL.createObjectURL(inputControl.files[0])` (where inputControl is a file input)

Comment: or make Uint8Array using FileReader ... or Blob

Comment: this asnwer usefull! thanks